# React + Redux: Why are props populated on third time load?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, axios

See my console log PROPS and the first two instances PROPS are empty then the third it is populated?

Why is that and is it possible to get around this so that the PROPS are populated on initial load?

My current stack for the application is React, Redux and using Axios to fetch JSON data from a CMS.

Screenshot: 
[image]

EDIT!!!!!

Here is my edit of my component with render function - see Footer for getData method:

```
componentWillMount() {
        //Fetch Ad Products Data
        this.props.dispatch(fetchAdProductsData())

        //Fetch List Ad Products Data
        this.props.dispatch(fetchListAdProductData())

        //Fetch Fox Footer Data
        this.props.dispatch(fetchFoxFooterData());

    }


    getData(prop) {
        if (prop.data === undefined) {
            return [{}];
        }

        return prop.data;
    }


    render(){
        let foxFooterData = this.props.foxFooterData;
        let listAdProductsData = this.props.listAdProductsData;

        return (
            <div className="ad-products-wrap container no-padding col-xs-12">
                <Header />
                <HeroModule />
                <HeroDetail />
                <ProductCategoryLeft />
                <ProductCategoryNavigation />
                <ProductCategoryRight />
                <ShowcaseModule />
                <NewsModule />
                <ContactModule />
                <Footer data={this.getData(foxFooterData)} />
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Having your props populated on initial load will slow the render process. But if you want so you could call it on `componentWillMount` hook.

Comment: I have a dispatch action indie a componentWillMount lifecycle and I'm mapping dispatch to props etc. Would it help to show you other pieces of code @ArchNoob

Comment: it is possible, quite often... I would recommend you to implement the `shouldComponentUpdate` method in order to render only when some props or some state change...

Comment: @assembler but when will I use my dispatch to fetch the JSON data if not in componentWillMount?

Comment: @Flith in `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 0):

1.) Call `FETCH_FOXFOOTER_DATA_COMPLETE` `componentDidMount`https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount.

2.) Remove `this.getData()` and leverage React's declarative nature. Inside the render function in your question pass props to `<Footer/>` and let that component handle missing props:

In `<Footer/>` :

```
render() {
  return (
    <footer>
      {props.data.length ? <DisplayDetailsThatNeedProps {...props} /> : <Loading />}
    </footer>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me an example of how to do this? The call to fetchFoxFooterData is being done in a componentWillMount method.

Comment: Please see my edit above also as per the docs use `componentDidMount` for data fetching https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: I have edited with my whole component function - hopefully this helps

Comment: @Filth please edit your question with your code not my answer

Comment: @Filth updated this answer accordingly to be more specific

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157926/discussion-between-filth-and-maxwelll).